# Unable to Export PDF, CSV, EXCEL in Display Tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, liferay, portlet, displaytag

I am using struts2, spring3, hibernate for my Liferay portlat application.

I used Display Tag 1.2 version and download displaytag-portlet, displaytag,displaytag-export-poi.

I also created displaytag.properties file and also add following line in it.

```
factory.requestHelper=org.displaytag.portlet.PortletRequestHelperFactory.
```

All is running well. Pagination, display, sorting all running well. But if I put **export="true"** in `<display:table>` then it displays me link for convert pdf, csv, Excel, rtc ..

But when I clicked on any Link like CSV it will gives me an error.

> 08:15:32,191 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-17][render_portlet_jsp:154] Exception: [.TableTag] Unable to reset response before returning exported data. You are not using an export filter. Be sure that no other jsp tags are used before display:table or refer to the displaytag documentation on how to configure the export filter (requires j2ee 1.3).
>       at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.writeExport(TableTag.java:1538)
>       at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.doExport(TableTag.java:1454)
>       at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.doEndTag(TableTag.java:1309)
>       at org.apache.jsp.pages.pim.employee.searchEmployee_jsp._jspService(searchEmployee_jsp.java:509)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)

What is the solution for this?

I also add filter in web.xml like:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions I can think of

1. What Andrea said
   Add this line of code **before** your struts2 filter in web.xml

   ```
   <filter>
     <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   ```
2. If your using multiple tables, increase the page buffer size of the JSP

   ```
    <%@ page buffer = "16kb" %>
   ```

You could try increasing your buffer size to 32kb or 64kb and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably in the portion of `web.xml` that you don't have written.

I guess you may have declared

- Struts2 **StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter** (or **FilterDispatcher** if S2 version < 2.1.x)
- DisplayTag **ResponseOverrideFilter**

In this case, the order is wrong, and you need to simply put the DisplayTag filter ***before*** the Struts2 filter.

Comment: Very firstly I done this things... Still same issue... I reordered as per your suggestion...
But failed....

Comment: yessssssss... I tried 2 days in this..... Most of suggestions from net surfing i implemented but faileddddddd